# IPhone UI - WebView VS Native screens

Tags: iphone, user-interface, jquery-ui, javascript-framework

in terms of performance and user interface experience , which one is better developing application in Html screens and JQtouch or building screens in C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "building screens in C++" do you mean "building a native interface in Objective-C?" You will definitely get better performance and user experience using a native interface over a web interface. That shouldn't be surprising. Most critically, you will be able to implement the kind of UI features that users expect, many of which are challenging to do well in Javascript. For instance, swipe to delete is a common interface element that is easy to implement natively, but is clunky in Javascript (I commend Google for trying in Gmail, but it's still clunky compared to native).